# NodeJS Strange response from JSON call

Tags: json, node.js

I got a strage response from my JSON call! This is my response output:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNQ0a.png)

And that's my JSON request:

```
request({
url: url,
json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body)
    }
})
```

I think it's something wrong about the charset, but i don't get how i can change this.

Solution:

```
// Had to decode url
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(name);
var url = "xxx" + encoded;
```

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` describes the **request** not the response.

Comment: You need to share the code you use to generate the response. We can't tell what it wrong with it by looking at the request.

Comment: @Quentin This is an example url which i use: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20UMP-45%20|%20Delusion%20(Minimal%20Wear)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://note.io/1H0DluY

Comment: @Quentin That's really strange... i've added my whole function below, can you check it also? thx

Comment: I don't know what arguments to call it with. Please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Quentin i've edited my code with the call

Comment: *ReferenceError: request is not defined*. If I add a require statement, that code outputs `0` and not the garbage in your screenshot so I still can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin it's working now! thanks for help... solution is in my code below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cleared a lot of misleading junk out of your code to get to the heart of the problem.

This now reproduces the original issue:

```
var request = require('request');

getItemPrice("StatTrak™ UMP-45 | Delusion (Minimal Wear)")

function getItemPrice(market_hash_name, callback) {
    var url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=" + market_hash_name;

    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(parseFloat(((body.lowest_price).replace(/\,/g, '.')).split('&')[0]));
        }
    })
}
```

Your problem is that what you are calling is not a valid URL and the server is reacting to it badly.

You must encode special characters into the URL format:

```
var url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(market_hash_name);
```

Comment: yep i also found the solution at the same time haha :) but thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score -1):

What kind of REST API do you call? If it's node js API, you can set the charset there

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```

And if that is not the case, set the request charset like this

```
request.setHeader('Accept-Charset', 'UTF-8)
```